# How we can inform to user that he needs to restart MAC after installing new application

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I need to inform user to restart his MAC after installing My application.

How is it possible?

Comment: A user should never need to restart after installing an app.

Comment: My application use services, The list of available services on the computer is built each time a user logs in. If your service is installed in an Applications directory, you need to log out and log back in before the service becomes available. I just need logout.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  You know how to write a Mac app, but you don't know how to show an alert?  I'm an iOS guy, but I can't imagine it's all that difficult.

Comment: Alert is possible but I need to create a .pkg file with restart option 
NB:This is my first MAC application